Integrating VLC Playback Trigger from Plex Web Interface on Raspberry Pi
I have a Raspberry Pi setup with Plex Media Server running smoothly, allowing me to stream videos seamlessly through the Plex web interface on various devices. Additionally, I've connected a TV to the Raspberry Pi via HDMI, where I utilize VLC player for direct video playback.
My goal is to initiate VLC playback on the Raspberry Pi directly from the Plex web interface. I'm familiar with launching VLC from the command line on the Raspberry Pi.
How can I trigger a command on the Raspberry Pi server through the Plex web interface? All I need  to pass to VLS is a filename with a file path.
Thank you for reading this (and, hopefully, sharing your ideas).
